# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() with jsoup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am a beginner in Android development and I'm getting this error that prevents my Asynctask from working using the UI:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I can't understand why. I'm using Android Studio. Before building it for release, my app worked fine but now it crashes. This is my class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, titleList);
    new NewThread().execute();
    return view;
}
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ot76.ru/mob/list.php?vt=" + (pageNumber + 1) + "&nl=0").get();
            title = doc.select("a");
            for (Element titles : title) {
                titleList.add(titles.html().replace("&nbsp;", "(") + ")    ");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String str = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Rasp.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", "http://ot76.ru/mob/getroutestr.php?vt=" + (pageNumber + 1) + "&nl=0&nmar=" + str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' ')).replace("к", "k").replace("а", "a").replace("б", "b").replace("с", "c").replace("д", "d"));
               intent.putExtra("stops", lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().substring(str.indexOf(' '), str.length() - 1));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: probably doc is null when you try yo access it

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. I just needed to add

`-keep public class org.jsoup.** { 
public *; 
}`

to my proguard-android.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems you are filling the `adapter` with *null* (ArrayList). So, you get `NPE` for that.

You should create the `adapter's object` for `ListView` in *onPostExecute(...)* after filling up the `titleList` otherwise it will *empty*. In *onCreateView(...)* `titleList` is *null*.

in *onCreateView(...)* create `titleList's` object.

```
titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

remove this line from *onCreateView(...)*

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, titleList);
```

in *onPostExecute(...)* populate `ListView` like this after filling up the value from *web service*

```
if(titleList != null) {
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, titleList);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**EDIT :**
Try to create `custom adapter` class and try to debug `doc` is not *null*.

Comment: Not work( Again this error. Screenshot: http://s018.radikal.ru/i501/1408/2c/7710d181ea22.png

Comment: what is variable named `in` ?

Comment: dont know.i no use this variable

Comment: check `doc` is null or not in `doInBackground(...)`

Comment: Problem solved. Need add -keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}    in proguard file